# ObserveEvent not triggered in nested module inserted with insertUI

Tags: r, shiny

I can create a module that inserts a button and triggers a `browser()` call inside an `observeEvent()` when the button is clicked:

```r
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("test"), "Test")
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$test, {
      browser()
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_ui("mod_top")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  mod_server("mod_top")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But if I insert this module inside another module using `insertUI`, the browser call is no longer triggered:

```r
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(
    id = ns("place_here"),
    actionButton(ns("add"), "Add")
  )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$add, {
      insertUI(
        immediate = TRUE,
        selector = paste0("#", ns("place_here")),
        where = "beforeEnd", 
        ui = mod_ui2(ns("mod_inner"))
      )
      mod_server2(ns("mod_inner"))
    })
  })
}

mod_ui2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("test"), "Test")
}

mod_server2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    browser()
  })
})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_ui("mod_top")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  mod_server("mod_top")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I trigger the browser call?

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you were trying to do. Needed to remove the ns() from mod_server2.  Also, as pointed out in previous response, needed to correct for input$test.

```
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    div(
        id = ns("place_here"),
        actionButton(ns("add"), "Add")
    )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        
        observeEvent(input$add, {
            ns <- session$ns
            insertUI(
                immediate = TRUE,
                selector = paste0("#", ns("place_here")),
                where = "beforeEnd", 
                ui = mod_ui2(ns("mod_inner"))
            )
            mod_server2("mod_inner")
        })
        
    })
}

mod_ui2 <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    actionButton(ns("test"), "Test")
}

mod_server2 <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        observeEvent(input$test, {
            browser()
        })
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    mod_ui("mod_top")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
    mod_server("mod_top")
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why does `mod_server2()` need to go in the main server function? What if you wanted to insert an arbitrary number of `mod_ui2()` and `mod_server2()`?

Comment: I understand better now what you were trying to do. See revised above. Just needed to remove the ns() from mod_server2 and correct for input$test.

Comment: Maybe you didn’t see it, but you literally just copied the answer I already posted.

Comment: Sorry, Giovanni, I didn't see and I was just trying to help. In your original question, I thought you were just looking to insert the UI and I was trying to show that you could fix the server side and still add the UI. With your follow up point that you were looking to add multiple modules, I approached the response differently. Good news is you discovered the problem with the ns() yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to remove the namespacing of the nested server module:

```r
mod_server2("mod_inner")
```

Here is the full working app:

```r
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  div(
    id = ns("place_here"),
    actionButton(ns("add"), "Add")
  )
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    observeEvent(input$add, {
      insertUI(
        immediate = TRUE,
        selector = paste0("#", ns("place_here")),
        where = "beforeEnd", 
        ui = mod_ui2(ns("mod_inner"))
      )
      mod_server2("mod_inner")
    })
  })
}

mod_ui2 <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("test"), "Test")
}

mod_server2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    browser()
  })
})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_ui("mod_top")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  mod_server("mod_top")
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```